# C++ Linear Allocator and Container Boundaries

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, containers, allocator

I am implementing a custom GUI/game engine, and have chosen to implement a heterogeneous resource manager system.  As a consequence of this, custom allocators are highly desirable for a number of situations.

One of the allocators I've identified for use, is a simple linear allocator.  My understanding is that a basic linear allocator is implemented something like this (without proper error handling for brevity):

```cpp
struct linear_allocator
{
    using value_type = std::byte;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    explicit linear_allocator(size_type n) noexcept
    {
        data = static_cast<pointer>(::operator new(n, std::nothrow_t{}));
    }

    ~linear_allocator() noexcept
    {
        ::operator delete(data, std::nothrow_t{});
    }

    [[nodiscard]] auto allocate(size_type n) noexcept -> pointer
    {
        auto temp = position;
        position += n;
        return temp;
    }

    auto deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) noexcept -> void
    {
        position = data;
    }

private:
    pointer data = nullptr;
    pointer position = nullptr;
};
```

My problem with this implementation, is in its statefulness.  Since this is an extremely performance critical component of my code, I am concerned that this is not optimal, and quite possibly error prone.

Because the allocator contains both pointers to the initial data root, and the position, it thus contains information about how to iterate through the memory, and the data size.  This means I either need to provide accessors to the member data, or provide duplicate book keeping information in the container that takes this allocator.

A better solution, in my eyes, is to have the container own the state information and leave the allocation to the container.  Thus, the container would contain all of the relevant information, and there is no duplicate book keeping.  Furthermore, the same behavior of a linear allocator would be achieved if allocation is only done in the containers' constructor, and deallocation is only done in the containers' destructor.  But if this is true, it seems that the allocator no longer needs a constructor or destructor, and I might as well be utilizing std::allocator.  And if this is the case... what is the purpose of a linear allocator?

I seem to have talked myself into thinking that a linear allocator is an antipattern.  What I am actually looking for is some kind of tightly-packed heterogeneous container, and linear allocators seem to be an odd merging of the allocator and container concepts.  A custom vector that stores a ledger (for index access if the heap contains objects of varying sizes) and a heap for data seems to be more along the lines of what is required.

Can someone please explain where the boundaries should be between allocators and containers are supposed to be (especially in the context of the Standard Library)?  I am assuming that there is error in my rationale.

**Edit**: Based on Eugene's suggestion below, I've rewritten my allocation/container scheme like the following (note, this is missing a copy/move constructor, assignment, etc, which I just deleted for the time being... but should be implemented properly at some point).  The main take away to the answer provided is that command_vector constructor and destructors are responsible for the allocations, and linear_allocator class is now stateless and simple.  The code roughly looks like the following (I realize I can and should probably be able to call alloc.allocate() one time rather than carving out 3 separate chunks here):

command_vector container class

```
template<typename key_t, typename alloc_t = linear_allocator<std::byte>>
struct command_vector
{
    using key_type = key_t;
    using value_type = std::byte;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using allocator = alloc_t;
    using iterator = command_packet*;
    using const_iterator = const iterator;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    explicit command_vector() noexcept :
        alloc{},
        keys{ alloc.allocate(packet_count) },
        packets{ alloc.allocate(packet_count) },
        packet_pos{ packets },
        heap{ alloc.allocate(heap_size) },
        heap_pos{ heap }
    {
        
    }

    explicit command_vector(size_type max_packets, size_type max_heap) noexcept :
        alloc{},
        keys{ alloc.allocate(max_packets) },
        packets{ alloc.allocate(max_packets) },
        packet_pos{ packets },
        heap{ alloc.allocate(max_heap) },
        heap_pos{ heap }
    {

    }

    constexpr command_vector(key_type* keys, pointer packets, pointer heap) noexcept requires std::is_same_v<alloc_t, null_allocator<value_type>> :
        alloc{},
        keys{ keys },
        packets{ packets },
        packet_pos{ packets },
        heap{ heap },
        heap_pos{ heap }
    {
        
    }

    constexpr command_vector(const command_vector&) noexcept = delete;
    constexpr command_vector(command_vector&&) noexcept = delete;
    constexpr auto operator=(const command_vector&) noexcept -> command_vector& = delete;
    constexpr auto operator=(command_vector&&) noexcept -> command_vector& = delete;

    ~command_vector() noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<allocator, null_allocator<value_type>>)
        {
            alloc.deallocate(packets);
            alloc.deallocate(heap);
        }
    }

    template<typename command_t>
    constexpr auto push_back(command_t&& command) noexcept -> void
    {
        *heap_pos   = command;
        *packet_pos = make_packet(std::forward<command_t>(command));

        heap_pos   += sizeof(std::decay_t<command_t>);
        ++packet_pos;
    }

    constexpr auto pop_back() noexcept -> void
    {
        --packet_pos;
        heap_pos = static_cast<pointer>(packet_pos->command);
    }

    constexpr auto clear() noexcept -> void
    {
        packet_pos = packets;
        heap_pos = heap;
    }

    constexpr auto size() noexcept -> difference_type
    {
        return packet_pos - packets;
    }

    constexpr auto begin()   -> iterator               { return packets;    }
    constexpr auto end()     -> iterator               { return packet_pos; }
    constexpr auto cbegin()  -> const_iterator         { return begin();    }
    constexpr auto cend()    -> const_iterator         { return end();      }
    constexpr auto rbegin()  -> reverse_iterator       { return end();      }
    constexpr auto rend()    -> reverse_iterator       { return begin();    }
    constexpr auto crbegin() -> const_reverse_iterator { return cend();     }
    constexpr auto crend()   -> const_reverse_iterator { return cbegin();   }

private:

    allocator alloc{};
    key_type* keys{};
    command_packet* packets{};
    command_packet* packet_pos{};
    pointer heap{};
    pointer heap_pos{};
};
```

null_allocator class

```
template<typename val_t>
struct null_allocator
{
    using value_type = val_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto allocate(size_type n) noexcept -> pointer
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    constexpr auto deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) noexcept -> void
    {
        
    }
};
```

linear_allocator class

```
template<typename val_t>
struct linear_allocator
{
    using value_type = val_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    [[nodiscard]] auto allocate(size_type n) noexcept -> pointer
    {
        return static_cast<pointer>(::operator new(n, std::nothrow_t{}));
    }

    auto deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) noexcept -> void
    {
        ::operator delete(p, std::nothrow_t{});
    }
};
```

Comment: Standard library allocators are probably doing a sys call for each allocation, which is on the order of 10k clock cycles. Your basic linear allocator is probably going to compile to 1 instruction, so on the order of one clock cycle. The few extra words of storage required to implement your allocator are then likely a worthwhile tradeoff, unless you are on a very memory constrained system.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if what you're saying is true. But isn't ::operator new an allocator that performs sys calls? Granted, I made this noexcept and generally removed a lot of error handling/checking that std::allocator probably performs, but removing the statefulness of the object more or less turns this (functionally speaking) back into std::allocator, correct?

Comment: @user2407038 I don't agree. C++ runtime library makes few system calls, pre-allocating memory in big chunks. Authors of the libraries are not stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please explain where the boundaries should be between allocators and
> containers are supposed to be

You should not start your design from allocators - they are implementation details. Start with the containers. Choose the container that has an interface you need, low algorithmic complexities of your most frequent operations, iterator invalidation guarantees, exception safety guarantees ...

Once you have that, measure the speed. If the program is too slow and your container is node-based, you *may be* able to speed it up by custom allocators. Of course, to beat the generic C++ dynamic memory mechanism, you have to know something special about your use pattern. For example, you may want to deallocate big chunks of memory at once.

**Edit:**
Containers hold all the state related to your problem. Allocators are usually stateless - stateful allocators were not even standard before C++11. Stateful allocators are intended to allocate memory from different memory pools and all the state is related to the pools.

Your `linear_allocator` has problems. First, `deallocate()` should be empty - all the memory should be freed in its dtor. Second, it does not handle copying - and this is the really difficult part - I am not sure what the right semantics is. Despite being an experienced C++ programmer, I would not dare to design this allocator myself.

> A custom vector that stores a ledger (for index access if the heap
> contains objects of varying sizes) and a heap for data seems to be
> more along the lines of what is required.

If you need a container of heterogeneous data, then this sounds right. For example, you may want `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>`. Alternatively, you may consider `std::vector<std::variant<..>>`. And, of course, you may need a container other than `std::vector<>`.

Comment: This is generally really good advice. I started my design from the data itself. I physically drew out what the memory needs to look like, and was able to find some benchmarks others have made. I am fairly certain that I need to allocate this particular chunk of memory up front. But I agree that if I'd started with the container, I probably would have seen the probably would have noticed the problem right away. Since it's the resource manager at the heart of the application, it will hold everything need to draw items to the screen, and therefore has a tight time constraint.

Comment: I really like this answer, but I am hesitant to mark it as accepted for the following reason:  It does not distinguish between the role of the container and the role of the allocator in terms of state.  I am also still confused about the use cases of a linear allocator (something I would consider to be a well-known type of allocator).  If the allocator is free and not owned by a container, the linear allocator pattern would make more sense to me.  Or, if the memory is global/static and used by multiple containers, this would make sense.  But this is not how I commonly see it used.

Comment: I have added a response to that in my answer, though it may still not satisfy you ... If you like the answer but feel you cannot accept it, then you can upvote it.

Comment: Actually, I think your edit cleared some things up.  I was not aware that c++ didn't have stateful allocators before c++11 (allocators are new (no pun intended) to me) since I am not allowed to use dynamic allocation on our embedded platforms at work.  For my implementation, I created a custom vector container and made this allocator stateless.  The container only calls allocate in the constructor and deallocate in the destructor.  The state is owned by the container as you suggested.  I will add my implementation for anyone who might find it useful.

Comment: While I am happy that you accepted the answer, I was not able to understand how your custom vector and its allocator are better than the standard ones. If you want somebody to look at your source, you may want to place it on Stack Exchange - Code Review site and explain its purpose.

Comment: In all honesty, that is part of my confusion.  In almost every scenario I see, std::allocator and std::pmr seem to fullfill the necessary requirements.  std::allocator can be used to create arenas, pools, and more.  And std::pmr can accept non-owning memory sources.  So in that sense, the more I dig at this, the less custom allocators seem to make sense to me.  Nevertheless, I think you gave me enough clarity to get me moving again.  In this particular instance, I'll probably move to a model that allocates once, with several containers that use this memory region.